# Getting value to display for Java CurrentAccount class

Tags: java

```
package bankAccount;

public class CurrentAccount {

        int account[];
        int lastMove;
        int startingBalance = 1000;

        CurrentAccount() {
            lastMove = 0;
            account = new int[10];
        }

        public void deposit(int value) {
            account[lastMove] = value;
            lastMove++;
        }

        public void draw(int value) {
            account[lastMove] = value;
            lastMove++;
        }

    public int settlement() {
           int result = 0;
           for (int i=0; i<account.length; i++) {
                  result = result + account[i] + startingBalance;

                  System.out.println("Result = " + result);

           }

           return result;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
                 CurrentAccount c = new CurrentAccount();
                  c.deposit(10);



        }
    }
```

At the moment, when I run the class, the expected System.out.println does not appear, and if I simply move public static void main(String[] args) to the top, this generates multiple red points.  What is the best way for me to refactor my code so it works in the expected way?

Comment: what do yo expect your program to print? Because in the actual version does not print anything.

Comment: When you say "System.out.println does not appear". Are you talking about the System.out in "settlement()" method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have another class called Main in the file Main.java in which you can write your

```
 public static void main(String args[])
```

and call

```
 c.settlement();
```

in you main() to print.

Also one more advice, 
in your constructor you have

```
account = new int[10];
```

which can hold only 10 `int`s.

in your deposit() and draw() you are not checking the `account` size. When the value of `lastMove` is more than 10 , the whole code blows up.

Hence I suggest you to use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

You never called the settlement method...

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    CurrentAccount c = new CurrentAccount();
    c.deposit(10);
    c.settlement();
}
```

I have the feeling that you come from some non-OOP language, like C or PHP. So some explanation:

- The `main` method is static: that means it "exists" even when there is no object instance created, it can be thought of as if it belonged to the class instance.

  - on the contrary, for the other methods to "work", an instance is required.
- This way the `main` method can be (and is actually) used as the entry point of the application
- It is executed, and when it exists, (if no other threads are left running) the application terminates.
- so nothing else is run that is outside of this method just by itself...

  - so if you don't call `c.settlement();` - it won't happen...

Other notes:

- Running `main` doesn't create an instance of the enclosing class
- with `new CurrentAccount()`, you create an object instance, which has states it stores, and can be manipulated
- be careful with arrays, they have to be taken care of, which tends to be inconvenient at times...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect the printed output to appear? You don't actually call the settlement method, so that command is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

You did not call settlement.. so nothing appears

if you add c.settlement... it is fine..

Answer (score 0):

You have not called `deposit()` and `settlement()` in the main method untill you call, You cannot get expected output.